# How Get width of a view using getWidth()?

Tags: java, android

How i can get Width or Height of a View in Android ?
when using getWidth() getHeight() methods they are returning 0

and another sub question is getWidth() return value in dp or px ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View's getWidth() and getHeight() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0)

Comment: It return 0 because view has't rendered yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view has not rendered yet. You have to wait it!

Use post method.

```
yourView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int height = yourView.getHeight();
            int width = yourView.getWidth();
        }
    });
```

**height and width value will be in pixel format**

If you get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

put your .post() code in a runOnUiThread method.

Comment: hi stappo could u help me over here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786965/facing-issue-while-validating-amongst-the-edittexts-in-recyclerview

Comment: hi android dev, today i'm busy but next days, if your question will be open i'll try to help you

Comment: but can you help me today im really in trouble ...i can also give my all points to you if you want